# Putting website titles into an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-excel, xlwt

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to get a list a website titles, and put them into an Excel spreadsheet.

Text file “c:\websites.txt” contains contents below:

```
www.dailynews.com
www.dailynews.lk
www.dailynews.co.zw
www.gulf-daily-news.com
www.dailynews.gov.bw
```

The workout:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import xlwt

list_open = open('c:\\websites.txt')
read_list = list_open.read()
line_in_list = read_list.split('\n')

for websites in line_in_list:

    url = "http://" + websites
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

    site_title = soup.find_all("title")

    print site_title
```

it works fine and generates the site titles. However when I add in below:

```
    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
    sheet = book.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

    for cor, lmn in enumerate(line_in_list):

        sheet.write (cor, 0, site_title)

book.save("C:\\site_titles.xls")
```

trying to have them nicely input into the column A of an Excel spread sheet, one by one, it doesn’t work.

Comment: thanks aspect_mkn8rd, please refer to below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you try to save a BeautifulSoup object

```
Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

Try to write the text value of that object and file will be written fine

```
for cor, lmn in enumerate(line_in_list):
    sheet.write (cor, 0, site_title[0].text)
```

Write loop is wrong, try it like this: 
Final script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import xlwt

line_in_list = ['www.dailynews.com','www.elpais.com'] #get urls from file
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8', style_compression = 0)
sheet = book.add_sheet('Sheet1', cell_overwrite_ok = True)

for cor,websites in enumerate(line_in_list):
    url = "http://" + websites
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
    site_title = soup.find_all("title")
    print site_title
    sheet.write (cor, 0, site_title[0].text)

book.save("site_titles.xls")
```

Comment: thanks xecgr. it works but all only writing the tile of last website 5 times into the Excel spreadsheet... where shall i do the fine-tuning?

Comment: xecgr, much appreciated. it's perfect!!